# CODE - UC SEG STATUS NOT ALLOWED-0003 when requesting EnhancedAirBookRQ

Tags: php, xml, curl, sabre

I am currently using CURL in PHP to request XML. When using same flow in POSTMAN service I can get the success result but, when using CURL in PHP I get CODE - UC SEG STATUS NOT ALLOWED-0003 status. Below are my CURL request header and code. Is my header option in CURL request making the problem?

```
 function get_xml_response($xmldata) {
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$wsdl = 'https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com';

$header = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: \"\"",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xmldata),
);

$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "$wsdl");
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmldata);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

  if (curl_exec($soap_do) === false) {
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
    return false;
  } else {
    $response = curl_exec($soap_do);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($soap_do, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    return $response;
  }
}
```

### EnhancedBookRQ.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">info@gandakiintl.com</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:ConversationId>111@gandakiintl.com</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service eb:type="SabreXML">Enhanced Air Book Request</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>EnhancedAirBookRQ</eb:Action>
      <eb:CPAID>T198</eb:CPAID>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>mid:11110info@gandakiintl.com</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2016-10-17T05-27-10Z</eb:Timestamp>
        <eb:TimeToLive>2016-10-17T05-27-10Z</eb:TimeToLive>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3322625022286234335!532307!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_6" version="3.6.0" HaltOnError="true">
      <OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UC"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="LL"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UL"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UN"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NO"/>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="HL"/>
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
          <FlightSegment NumberInParty="1" Status="NN" FlightNumber="281" ResBookDesigCode="W" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T13:10:00" ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-13T14:40:00">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
            <Equipment AirEquipType="73H"/>
            <MarketingAirline FlightNumber="281" Code="9W"/>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
          </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
      </OTA_AirBookRQ>
      <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
          <OptionalQualifiers>
            <FlightQualifiers>
              <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Code="9W"/>
              </VendorPrefs>
            </FlightQualifiers>
            <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="NPR">
              <PassengerType Code="ADT" Force="true" Quantity="1"/>
              <Taxes>
                <TaxExempt Code="NQ"/>
              </Taxes>
            </PricingQualifiers>
          </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
      </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
      <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
        <RedisplayReservation/>
      </PostProcessing>
      <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false">            </PreProcessing>
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

### EnhancedBookRS.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">info@gandakiintl.com</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>T198</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>111@gandakiintl.com</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service eb:type="SabreXML">Enhanced Air Book Request</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>EnhancedAirBookRS</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>bk97jgyj2</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2017-01-03T06:01:43</eb:Timestamp>
        <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:11110info@gandakiintl.com</eb:RefToMessageId>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3322625022286234335!532307!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_6">
      <ns2:ApplicationResults xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="NotProcessed">
        <ns2:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-01-03T00:01:43.090-06:00">
          <ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
            <ns2:Message code="ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">CODE - UC SEG STATUS NOT ALLOWED-0003</ns2:Message>
          </ns2:SystemSpecificResults>
        </ns2:Error>
      </ns2:ApplicationResults>
      <OTA_AirBookRS>
        <OriginDestinationOption>
          <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="04-13T14:40" DepartureDateTime="04-13T13:10" FlightNumber="0281" NumberInParty="001" ResBookDesigCode="W" Status="NN" eTicket="true">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
            <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="0281"/>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
          </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationOption>
      </OTA_AirBookRS>
      <TravelItineraryReadRS>
        <TravelItinerary>
          <CustomerInfo/>
          <ItineraryInfo>
            <ItineraryPricing>
              <PriceQuote RPH="1">
                <MiscInformation>
                  <SignatureLine ExpirationDateTime="00:00" Source="SYS" Status="ACTIVE">
                    <Text>T198 T198*AGT 1131/03JAN17</Text>
                  </SignatureLine>
                  <TicketingFees Disclaimer="ONE OR MORE FORM OF PAYMENT FEES MAY APPLY"/>
                  <TicketingFees Disclaimer="ACTUAL TOTAL WILL BE BASED ON FORM OF PAYMENT USED"/>
                  <TicketingFees Disclaimer="FEE CODE     DESCRIPTION                         FEE">
                    <FeeInformation Amount="399" CurrenyCode="" Description="" FunctionCode="FCA" ServiceType="OB">- ANY CC</FeeInformation>
                  </TicketingFees>
                </MiscInformation>
                <PricedItinerary DisplayOnly="false" InputMessage="WPA9WMNPRP1ADTXOTE-NQRQ" RPH="1" StatusCode="A" TaxExempt="false" ValidatingCarrier="9W">
                  <AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                    <ItinTotalFare>
                      <BaseFare Amount="3425" CurrencyCode="NPR"/>
                      <Taxes>
                        <Tax Amount="6377" TaxCode="XT"/>
                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">0NQ</TaxBreakdownCode>
                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">791NP</TaxBreakdownCode>
                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">1000B6</TaxBreakdownCode>
                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">1159IN</TaxBreakdownCode>
                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">3427YQ</TaxBreakdownCode>
                      </Taxes>
                      <TotalFare Amount="9802" CurrencyCode="NPR"/>
                      <Totals>
                        <BaseFare Amount="3425"/>
                        <Taxes>
                          <Tax Amount="6377"/>
                        </Taxes>
                        <TotalFare Amount="9802"/>
                      </Totals>
                    </ItinTotalFare>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="01"/>
                    <PTC_FareBreakdown>
                      <Endorsements>
                        <Endorsement type="SYSTEM_ENDORSEMENT">
                          <Text>NON ENDO</Text>
                        </Endorsement>
                        <Endorsement type="PRICING_PARAMETER">
                          <Text>WPA9W$MNPR$P1ADT$XO$TE-NQ$RQ</Text>
                        </Endorsement>
                        <Endorsement type="WARNING">
                          <Text>VALIDATING CARRIER SPECIFIED - 9W</Text>
                        </Endorsement>
                      </Endorsements>
                      <FareBasis Code="W2STOWNP"/>
                      <FareCalculation>
                        <Text>KTM 9W DEL Q15.00 16.61NUC31.61END ROE108.347088</Text>
                      </FareCalculation>
                      <FareSource>ATPC</FareSource>
                      <FlightSegment ConnectionInd="O" DepartureDateTime="04-13T13:10" FlightNumber="281" ResBookDesigCode="W" SegmentNumber="1" Status="OK">
                        <BaggageAllowance Number="20K"/>
                        <FareBasis Code="W2STOWNP"/>
                        <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="281"/>
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
                        <ValidityDates>
                          <NotValidAfter>2017-04-13</NotValidAfter>
                          <NotValidBefore>2017-04-13</NotValidBefore>
                        </ValidityDates>
                      </FlightSegment>
                      <FlightSegment>
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
                      </FlightSegment>
                      <ResTicketingRestrictions>LAST DAY TO PURCHASE 10JAN/2359</ResTicketingRestrictions>
                      <ResTicketingRestrictions>GUARANTEED FARE APPL IF PURCHASED BEFORE 10JAN</ResTicketingRestrictions>
                    </PTC_FareBreakdown>
                  </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                </PricedItinerary>
                <ResponseHeader>
                  <Text>FARE - PRICE RETAINED</Text>
                  <Text>FARE USED TO CALCULATE DISCOUNT</Text>
                  <Text>FARE NOT GUARANTEED UNTIL TICKETED</Text>
                </ResponseHeader>
                <PriceQuotePlus DiscountAmount="0" DisplayOnly="false" DomesticIntlInd="I" IT_BT_Fare="BT" ItineraryChanged="false" ManualFare="false" NUCSuppresion="false" NegotiatedFare="false" PricingStatus="M" SubjToGovtApproval="false" SystemIndicator="S" VerifyFareCalc="false">
                  <TicketingInstructionsInfo/>
                </PriceQuotePlus>
              </PriceQuote>
              <PriceQuoteTotals>
                <BaseFare Amount="3425.00"/>
                <Taxes>
                  <Tax Amount="6377.00"/>
                </Taxes>
                <TotalFare Amount="9802.00"/>
              </PriceQuoteTotals>
            </ItineraryPricing>
            <ReservationItems>
              <Item RPH="1">
                <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0507" ArrivalDateTime="04-13T14:40" DayOfWeekInd="4" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T13:10" ElapsedTime="01.45" FlightNumber="0281" IsPast="false" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="W" SegmentNumber="0001" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="SS" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="true">
                  <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="TERMINAL 3" TerminalCode="3"/>
                  <Equipment AirEquipType="73H"/>
                  <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="0281"/>
                  <Meal Code="L"/>
                  <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
                  <SupplierRef ID="DC9W"/>
                  <UpdatedArrivalTime>04-13T14:40</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                  <UpdatedDepartureTime>04-13T13:10</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                </FlightSegment>
              </Item>
              <Item RPH="2">
                <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0507" ArrivalDateTime="04-13T14:40" DayOfWeekInd="4" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T13:10" ElapsedTime="01.45" FlightNumber="0281" IsPast="false" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="W" SegmentNumber="0002" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="UC" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                  <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="TERMINAL 3" TerminalCode="3"/>
                  <Equipment AirEquipType="73H"/>
                  <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="0281"/>
                  <Meal Code="L"/>
                  <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
                  <SupplierRef ID="DC9W"/>
                  <UpdatedArrivalTime>04-13T14:40</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                  <UpdatedDepartureTime>04-13T13:10</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                </FlightSegment>
              </Item>
            </ReservationItems>
          </ItineraryInfo>
          <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1B">
            <Header>CURRENTLY DISPLAYING A PNR OWNED BY THE SABRE PRIME HOST</Header>
            <Header>RULES AND FUNCTIONALITY FOR THAT PRIME HOST WILL APPLY</Header>
            <Header>PRICE QUOTE RECORD - MODIFIED</Header>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="T198"/>
          </ItineraryRef>
          <SpecialServiceInfo RPH="001" Type="GFX">
            <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
              <Airline Code="1B"/>
              <Text>PLEASE TICKET FARE AS PER TKT/TL IN PQ</Text>
            </Service>
          </SpecialServiceInfo>
        </TravelItinerary>
      </TravelItineraryReadRS>
    </EnhancedAirBookRS>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Comment: There is no javascript

Comment: Mistaken. Removed tag.

Comment: @user254153 you say the request works in postman. show us your postman request details

Comment: the request i posted is same in postman also. it works in postman but not with php curl

Comment: @user254153 but here can be nuance. +1 to see postman screenshot

Comment: its same as posted in question

Comment: Who knows, it can be same only for you, not for other... :) Tell - are you using "x-www-form-urlencoded" or "form-data" in postman to send request?

Comment: I my self copy and pasted the same xml document from post man. I am using raw with text/xml in postman.

Comment: @user254153 I see. Yes. in that case it should be same. I did try your request in Postman and in curl - in both I had answer "errors.session.USG_INVALID_SECURITY_TOKEN". Not sure if that is good idea - provide here your session token. But if you want - I can try once more and we will see if I have another answer from API than you. It will means that there is nuance specially with your CURL.

Comment: Security token is dynamically created from the another xml request before requesting enhanvedairRQ xml in the server. I am sure there is no issues with security token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132985/discussion-between-vladimir-gilevich-and-user254153).

Answer (score 3):

I have to check your code, One thing is that if you getting your result from postman .. Then there is a  good option for getting curl code from the postman.  By click on code > change HTTP option  to PHP curl  >copy to clipboard . If you try with this way of write code, you have to change little changes.

And one more thing, A very good answer have given here [UC status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263867/error-code-uc-seg-status-not-allowed) . UC status related to UN-CONFIRMED status. Please have a look here. Thanks

This is an example , for how to pass your post field data in xml form :

```
 $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_PORT => "",
      CURLOPT_URL => "url here",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <soap:Body> soap body part </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: text/xml"
      ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
```

Comment: I got it already working copying the code from post man itself. But I want to know why its not working in my CURL request. Is it the problem of my header.

Comment: @user254153 Can you please share your curl code getting from postman.

Comment: $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xmldata,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: text/xml"
//    "postman-token: 1bf536a9-55a2-fbf7-6e04-0f2bf4abebff"
  ),
));

Comment: I think you should pass $xmldata in form of xml in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>   please try with this e.g. code e.g. i have edit my answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried you code and modified some part of it. please try using below code

```
        <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    $xmldata='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
    <eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">info@gandakiintl.com</eb:PartyId>
    </eb:From>
    <eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
    </eb:To>
    <eb:ConversationId>111@gandakiintl.com</eb:ConversationId>
    <eb:Service eb:type="SabreXML">Enhanced Air Book Request</eb:Service>
    <eb:Action>EnhancedAirBookRQ</eb:Action>
    <eb:CPAID>T198</eb:CPAID>
    <eb:MessageData>
    <eb:MessageId>mid:11110info@gandakiintl.com</eb:MessageId>
    <eb:Timestamp>2016-10-17T05-27-10Z</eb:Timestamp>
    <eb:TimeToLive>2016-10-17T05-27-10Z</eb:TimeToLive>
    </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3322625022286234335!532307!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
    <EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_6" version="3.6.0" HaltOnError="true">
    <OTA_AirBookRQ>
    <HaltOnStatus Code="UC"/>
    <HaltOnStatus Code="LL"/>
    <HaltOnStatus Code="UL"/>
    <HaltOnStatus Code="UN"/>
    <HaltOnStatus Code="NO"/>
    <HaltOnStatus Code="HL"/>
    <OriginDestinationInformation>
    <FlightSegment NumberInParty="1" Status="NN" FlightNumber="281" ResBookDesigCode="W" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T13:10:00" ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-13T14:40:00">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
    <Equipment AirEquipType="73H"/>
    <MarketingAirline FlightNumber="281" Code="9W"/>
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
    </FlightSegment>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    </OTA_AirBookRQ>
    <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
    <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
    <OptionalQualifiers>
    <FlightQualifiers>
    <VendorPrefs>
    <Airline Code="9W"/>
    </VendorPrefs>
    </FlightQualifiers>
    <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="NPR">
    <PassengerType Code="ADT" Force="true" Quantity="1"/>
    <Taxes>
    <TaxExempt Code="NQ"/>
    </Taxes>
    </PricingQualifiers>
    </OptionalQualifiers>
    </PriceRequestInformation>
    </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
    <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
    <RedisplayReservation/>
    </PostProcessing>
    <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false">            </PreProcessing>
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
    </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Envelope>';

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $wsdl = 'https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com';

    $header = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: \"\"",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($xmldata),
    );
        $ch = curl_init();      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wsdl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmldata); // the SOAP request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);     
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_error($ch);
       print_r($response);
       print_r($err);

    ?>
```

Comment: what you have modified

Comment: curl call request and added content type at the beginning. What exactly problem you are facing?. The wsdl which you have provided is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the sabre api, but it Looks like you malformed the request with the segement UC.

Try to look in the api docs or try to contact the help desk.

In the sample request there es is no `<haltonstatus/>`, Look here 
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/orchestrated_air_booking

Comment: I contacted them. They tried with POSTMAN api request service all workflow are working well. Even when I tried with POSTMAN I can successfully get it working. But with PHP CURL request it is giving UC status. So I guess its error in my CURL request. In the sample request there es is no -> I am not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: Oh sorry, i typed it on mobile... In the sample there is no  <HaltOnStatus/>, what will happen, if you leave it out..

Comment: HaltOnStatus will halt the process if there is any status mentioned there like UC in my case and other status.

Answer (score 0):

UC status means that the itinerary you booked is not available. It could be due to a number of different things like date, class of service, etc.

Where did you get the itinerary information from? If you're using a shopping service, I'd advise you to run it again and see if the same itinerary is still returned, or if the class of service changed.

Comment: I got iteinerary information from BargainFinderMaxRQ. I am confused in one thing that. When I book for flight number 259 and in EnhancedBookRQ, I get 2 flightsegment of same flight number (259) with satatus UC and SS. What does that mean?. But I get UC status as error and status not processed.

Comment: Maybe you run the request 2 times? UC is an invalid status and you should ignore (remove) that segment. SS is a valid status.

Comment: No there is only one request.

Answer (score 0):

Write xml content to a file named is soap_this.xml and using curl command to send request:
`curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @soap_get.xml your_url`

Answer (score 0):

That because by the time you creating pnr request, there might not be a available flight for your requesting cabin type. Even though atleast one flight sector has unavailability Sabre does not allow to create pnr

Using following Sabre commands you can check availability of flight segments

[image]

More details about commands: http://www.emquest.ae/downloads/STM/Quick%20Reference%20English.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In your Request you have set this option:

```
<HaltOnStatus Code="UC"/>
<HaltOnStatus Code="LL"/>
<HaltOnStatus Code="UL"/>
<HaltOnStatus Code="UN"/>
<HaltOnStatus Code="NO"/>
<HaltOnStatus Code="HL"/>
```

which means if the segment that you are trying to sell is not confirmed because of availability etc then end the transaction.